How do portals in Duke Nukem 3D traverse into other sectors properly while keeping things rendering normally?
I'm making a very simple portal based software renderer in PyGame that just uses portals as links to other sectors - like a window or doorway. I've have gotten somewhat far, with texture mapping (thank you Plus-Dust), entities, and some other neat things. I'm going ahead with a portal based SW renderer because a depth buffer was apparently too difficult for me to add previously and that I'm not wanting to do BSP at the moment due to limited time, so I'm not doing anything fancy that makes a portal a proper portal - one that transforms a sector and puts it infront of the portal as if it were a doorway.
Forgive the fact that I may sound like an idiot, but my problem starts with the portal traversal. For example, we'll have 3 sectors. We have sector A, B, and C. A goes into C, B goes into C and C goes both into A AND B. My problem is in the form of the incorrect sector being drawn, as C would sometimes overlap C. My portal rendering system works by first getting the portals in the current sector I am in, then if the portal is visible, I then go to the sector linked by that sector and append the sector I was in before to an array, so I make sure NOT to go back there. During the drawing process, I check if there is a pixel already assigned to where I am wanting to draw. If there isn't, I draw my pixel.
I've tried making the linked sectors for the portals render within the portal bounds on the screen, and I've tried appending my portals instead of the sectors to an array so I don't somehow go backwards on accident, but that doesn't work either. Any advice on what I should do? Also, apologies for the upcoming spaghetti code. I'll be happy to answer any questions asked.



engine.py;
from settings import *
import level
import raster
import classes

screenArray = blankScreenArray.copy()
sectors_traversed = []

def lerp(t, a, b):
    return a + t * (b - a)

class Engine:
    def __init__(self, player, main_screen, logical_screen, textures):
        ## globals
        global screenArray

        screenArray=blankScreenArray.copy()
        self.screen=logical_screen
        self.main_screen=main_screen
        self.player:classes.Player=player
        self.textures=textures
        self.traversed_portals=[]
        
    def renderWall(self, wx1, wy1, wx2, wy2, z0, z1, f, c, fillPortal, visPlane, ceiling_c, floor_c, t0, t1, wall_length, fov, yaw, wall_texture, floor_texture, ceiling_texture, floor_texture_scale, ceiling_texture_scale, ceiling_distance, floor_distance, wall_height, wall_is_sky, ceiling_is_sky, v_offset, lighting):
        cx, cy = self.player.x, self.player.y

        current_ceiling_lut = [0]*W
        current_floor_lut = [H1]*W

        sx1, sy1 = raster.transformToScreen(f, (wx1, wy1, z0))
        sx2, sy2 = raster.transformToScreen(f, (wx2, wy2, z0))
        sy3 = raster.transformYCoordToScreen(f, (wx1, wy1, z1))
        sy4 = raster.transformYCoordToScreen(f, (wx2, wy2, z1))

        current_ceiling_lut, current_floor_lut = raster.rasterizeTextured(screenArray, sx1, sx2, sy1, sy2, sy3, sy4, c, fillPortal, portal_buffer, current_ceiling_lut, current_floor_lut, wall_texture, wy1, wy2, t0, t1, wall_length, wall_height, wall_is_sky, self.player.yaw, v_offset, lighting)
        yaw = np.radians(yaw)
        if visPlane == -1:
            raster.rasterizeVisplane(screenArray, current_ceiling_lut, floor_texture, floor_texture_scale, fov, f, yaw, cx, cy, floor_distance, False, lighting, floor_c)
            raster.rasterizeVisplane(screenArray, current_floor_lut, ceiling_texture, ceiling_texture_scale, fov, f, yaw, cx, cy, ceiling_distance, ceiling_is_sky, lighting, ceiling_c)
        elif visPlane == 1:
            raster.rasterizeVisplane(screenArray, current_ceiling_lut, floor_texture, floor_texture_scale, fov, f, yaw, cx, cy, floor_distance, False, lighting, floor_c)
        elif visPlane == 2:
            raster.rasterizeVisplane(screenArray, current_floor_lut, ceiling_texture, ceiling_texture_scale, fov, f, yaw, cx, cy, ceiling_distance, ceiling_is_sky, lighting, ceiling_c)

    def renderSector(self, sector, yaw):
        if sector in sectors_traversed:
            return
        cx, cy, cz = self.player.x, self.player.y, self.player.z
        cs, sn = cos[yaw], sin[yaw]
        if sector == None:
            print('No Reference Sector; Out of Bounds or Missing Sector?')
            return
        sector_elevation = sector.e
        sector_height = sector.h
        sector_entities = sector.entities
        ceiling_c = sector.cc
        floor_c = sector.fc
        f = self.player.FocalLength
        fov = self.player.FOV
        portal_buffer=blankScreenArray.copy()
        portal_queue = []
        cz = self.player.z+self.player.h
        floor_distance = cz-sector.e
        ceiling_distance = sector.e+sector.h-cz
        # do entity rendering first
        for entity in sector_entities:
            wx0, wy0 = raster.transformVector((entity.x-cx, entity.y-cy), cs, sn)
            if wy0 < 1:
                continue
            sprite = self.textures[entity.sprite][0]
            e=cz-entity.z-entity.h
            sx0, sy0 = raster.transformToScreen(f, (wx0, wy0, e))
            raster.rasterizeSprite(screenArray, sx0, sy0, sprite, wy0, entity.scale, f)
            
        lighting = sector.lighting
        # do wall rendering last
        for wall in sector.walls:
            wall_p1 = wall.p1
            wall_p2 = wall.p2
            c=wall.c
            rx1 = wall_p1[0]-cx
            ry1 = wall_p1[1]-cy
            rx2 = wall_p2[0]-cx
            ry2 = wall_p2[1]-cy

            def_01_is_portal = wall.def_1_portal
            def_01_portal_link = wall.def_1_link

            wall_texture=wall.wall_texture
            floor_texture=wall.floor_texture
            ceiling_texture=wall.ceiling_texture
            floor_texture_scale=wall.floor_texture_scale
            ceiling_texture_scale=wall.ceiling_texture_scale

            wall_length = wall.length
            wall_height = sector_height+sector_elevation
            t0, t1 = 0, 1
            wx1, wy1 = raster.transformVector((rx1, ry1), cs, sn)
            wx2, wy2 = raster.transformVector((rx2, ry2), cs, sn)
            
            if wy1 < 1:
                wx1, wy1, t = raster.clip(wx1, wy1, wx2, wy2, 1, 1, W, 1)
                t1 += t/self.player.fovWidthAtY
            elif wy2 < 1:
                wx2, wy2, t = raster.clip(wx2, wy2, wx1, wy1, 1, 1, W, 1)
                t0 -= t/self.player.fovWidthAtY

            ## figure out what side we're at relative to the segment
            wall_normal_x = wall_p2[1]-wall_p1[1]
            wall_normal_y = -(wall_p2[0]-wall_p1[0])
            side = (wall_normal_x * rx1) + (wall_normal_y * ry1)
            side = side > 0 and 1 or side < 0 and -1 or 0
            # 1 = Right, -1 = Left, 0 = Colinear
            # we find out what side is being drawn, check if we can draw a portal and change how we rasterize the wall
            portal_to_render = None

            wall_is_sky = wall_texture[2] == 'sky'
            ceiling_is_sky = ceiling_texture[2] == 'sky'
            
            wall_texture = wall_texture[0]
            floor_texture = floor_texture[0]
            ceiling_texture = ceiling_texture[0]
            
            if def_01_is_portal:
                portal_to_render = def_01_portal_link

            if side == -1:
                if portal_to_render == None:
                    if wy1 > 1 and wy2 > 1:
                        z0 = cz-sector_elevation
                        z1 = z0-sector_height
                        self.renderWall(wx1, wy1, wx2, wy2, z0, z1, f, c, False, -1, ceiling_c, floor_c, t0, t1, wall_length, fov, yaw, wall_texture, floor_texture, ceiling_texture, floor_texture_scale, ceiling_texture_scale, ceiling_distance, floor_distance, wall_height, wall_is_sky, ceiling_is_sky, 0, lighting)
                    else:
                        continue
                else:
                    portal_bottom = wall.portal_bottom
                    portal_top = wall.portal_top
                    # we have a portal, so we are going to split the sector into two first. we will also check how high and how low can the portal be?
                    wall_bottom = cz-sector_elevation # this is the bottom of the sector
                    wall_portion_01 = wall_bottom-portal_bottom
                    #wall_height_bottom = portal_bottom
                    wall_top = wall_bottom-sector_height # this is the top of the sector
                    wall_portion_02 = wall_top+portal_top
                    #wall_height_top = portal_top
                    if wy1 > 1 and wy2 > 1:
                        wall_height = portal_bottom
                        self.renderWall(wx1, wy1, wx2, wy2, wall_bottom, wall_portion_01, f, c, False, 1, ceiling_c, floor_c, t0, t1, wall_length, fov, yaw, wall_texture, floor_texture, ceiling_texture, floor_texture_scale, ceiling_texture_scale, ceiling_distance, floor_distance, wall_height, wall_is_sky, ceiling_is_sky, -40, lighting)
                        wall_height = portal_top
                        self.renderWall(wx1, wy1, wx2, wy2, wall_portion_02, wall_top, f, c, False, 2, ceiling_c, floor_c, t0, t1, wall_length, fov, yaw, wall_texture, floor_texture, ceiling_texture, floor_texture_scale, ceiling_texture_scale, ceiling_distance, floor_distance, wall_height, wall_is_sky, ceiling_is_sky, 0, lighting)
                        wall_height = sector_height+sector_elevation
                    # we now know where we rendered the bottom of the top portion and the top of the bottom portion, now we can draw the portal
                    if not sector in portal_queue:
                        sx1, sy1 = raster.transformToScreen(f, (wx1, wy1, wall_portion_01))
                        sx2, sy2 = raster.transformToScreen(f, (wx2, wy2, wall_portion_01))
                        sy3 = raster.transformYCoordToScreen(f, (wx1, wy1, wall_portion_02))
                        sy4 = raster.transformYCoordToScreen(f, (wx2, wy2, wall_portion_02))
                        #portal_occluded = raster.is_portal_visible(screenArray, sx1, sx2, sy1, sy2, sy3, sy4)
                        portalSector = level.sectors[portal_to_render]
                        portal_center = (wall.p1+wall.p2)/2
                        portal_array = [portalSector, sx1, sx2, sy1, sy2, sy3, sy4, wall]
                        portal_queue.append(portal_array)
        ## render portals   
        if len(portal_queue) > 0:
            for portalArray in portal_queue:
                portal_linked_sector, sx1, sx2, sy1, sy2, sy3, sy4, wall = portalArray
                if not wall in self.traversed_portals:
                    self.traversed_portals.append(wall)
                    # we will visualize the portals first
                    obstructed = raster.rasterizePortal(screenArray, portal_buffer, sx1, sx2, sy1, sy2, sy3, sy4, PINK, 1)
                    if not obstructed:
                        pass
                    self.renderSector(portal_linked_sector, yaw)

    def update(self, dt):
        ## globals
        global screenArray, portal_buffer, sectors_traversed
        sectors_traversed = []
        portal_buffer = blank_portal_buffer.copy()
        in_sector = self.find_sector_from_point(self.player.x, self.player.y)
        if in_sector != None:
            self.player.currentSector = in_sector
        if self.player.currentSector != None:
            self.player.vz -= 9.82
            self.player.z += self.player.vz/dt
            if self.player.z < self.player.currentSector.e:
                # they've hit the floor
                self.player.vz = 0
                if self.player.hasJumped:
                    if pygame.time.get_ticks()-self.player.jumpTick >= 2/dt:
                        self.player.hasJumped = False
                        # we're on the ground and the cooldown is above 2
            elif self.player.z > self.player.currentSector.e+self.player.currentSector.h-self.player.h:
                self.player.vz = 0
                # they hit the ceiling
            self.player.z = min(max(self.player.z, self.player.currentSector.e), self.player.currentSector.e+self.player.currentSector.h-self.player.h)
            ## update all entities coordinates and put them in the correct sectors
            # when the entity moves, and has a velocity > 0, we will check if it is inside a new sector and set it to the new sector if so
            for sector in level.sectors:
                for entity in sector.entities:
                    entity.update(dt, self, sector, entity)
                    if entity.isTouchable:
                        entity.checkTouch(self.player.x, self.player.y, sector, entity)
            ## draw the current sector
            yaw = int(self.player.yaw)%360
            self.renderSector(self.player.currentSector, yaw)
            self.traversed_portals = []
    def draw(self):
        ## globals
        global screenArray

        pygame.surfarray.blit_array(self.screen, screenArray)
        scaled_surface = pygame.transform.scale(self.screen, (640, 480))
        self.main_screen.blit(scaled_surface, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()
        screenArray = blankScreenArray.copy()
        """buffer = (ctypes.c_uint8 * (W * H * 3)).from_buffer(screenArray)
        ctypes.memset(ctypes.addressof(buffer), 0, len(buffer))"""
        
    def point_in_polygon(self, cx, cy, walls):
        # Cast a ray to the right and count intersections
        intersections = 0
        for wall in walls:
            p1 = wall.p1
            p2 = wall.p2
            x0, y0 = p1
            x1, y1 = p2
            # Check if the point is on an edge
            if (min(y0, y1) <= cy < max(y0, y1)) and (cx < max(x0, x1)):
                if (y1 - y0) != 0:  # Avoid division by zero
                    x_intersection = x0 + (cy - y0) * (x1 - x0) / (y1 - y0)
                    if cx < x_intersection:
                        intersections += 1
        return intersections % 2 == 1
    
    def find_sector_from_point(self, x, y):
        for sector in level.sectors:
            sector_walls = sector.walls
            is_inside_sector = self.point_in_polygon(x, y, sector_walls)
            if is_inside_sector:
                return sector
        return None

raster.py
from settings import *

@staticmethod
@njit
def transformVector(v, cs, sn):
    x, y = v
    tx = x*cs-y*sn
    ty = y*cs+x*sn
    return (tx, ty)

@staticmethod
@njit
def transformToScreen(f, v):
    x, y, z = v
    inv_y = 1 / y  # Avoid repeated division
    return (x * inv_y * f + W2, z * inv_y * f + H2)


@staticmethod
@njit
def transformYCoordToScreen(f, v):
    _, y, z = v
    inv_y = 1 / y  # Avoid repeated division
    return z * inv_y * f + H2

# Yuriy Georgiev
@staticmethod
@njit
def clip(ax, ay, bx, by, px1, py1, px2, py2):
    a = (px1 - px2) * (ay - py2) - (py1 - py2) * (ax - px2)
    b = (py1 - py2) * (ax - bx) - (px1 - px2) * (ay - by)
    t = a / (b+1)
    ax -= t * (bx - ax)
    ay -= t * (by - ay)
    return ax, ay, t

@staticmethod
@njit
def rasterizeVisplane(screenArray, lut, texture, texture_scale, fov, f, yaw, cx, cy, elevation, is_sky, lighting, c):
    tanFOV=np.tan(fov/2)
    for x in prange(1, W1):
        Y = lut[x]
        if not is_sky:
            beta = x/W1*fov-fov/2
            alpha = (yaw+beta)
            cos_beta = np.cos(beta)
            sin_alpha = np.sin(alpha)
            cos_alpha = np.cos(alpha)
        else:
            angle = np.atan((x-W2)/W2*tanFOV)
            adjusted_angle = np.degrees(yaw + angle)
            texX = int(adjusted_angle/360*texture.shape[0])%texture.shape[0]
        
        direction = Y > H2
        if direction:
            for y in prange(Y, H1):
                if not (x > W1 or x < 1 or y > H1 or y < 1):
                    colAvg = (screenArray[x, y][0]+screenArray[x, y][1]+screenArray[x, y][2])/3
                    isFilled = colAvg > 0
                    if not isFilled:
                        if not is_sky:
                            r = abs(y-H2)
                            straightDist = (elevation*f)/r
                            d = (straightDist/cos_beta)
                            wx = cx + (sin_alpha*d)
                            wy = cy + (cos_alpha*d)

                            texX = int(wx*texture_scale)%texture.shape[0]
                            texY = int(wy*texture_scale)%texture.shape[1]

                            texture_clr = texture[texX, texY]
                            screenArray[x, y] = (texture_clr[0], texture_clr[1], texture_clr[2])
                        else:
                            if y < texture.shape[1]:
                                texY = int(y)%texture.shape[1]
                                texture_col = texture[texX, texY]
                                texture_col = [
                                    max(texture_col[0], 0),
                                    max(texture_col[1], 0),
                                    max(texture_col[2], 0)
                                ]
                                screenArray[x, y] = texture_col
        else:
            for y in prange(1, Y):
                if not (x > W1 or x < 1 or y > H1 or y < 1):
                    colAvg = (screenArray[x, y][0]+screenArray[x, y][1]+screenArray[x, y][2])/3
                    isFilled = colAvg > 0
                    if not isFilled:
                        if not is_sky:
                            r = abs(y-H2)
                            straightDist = (elevation*f)/r
                            d = (straightDist/cos_beta)
                            wx = cx + (sin_alpha*d)
                            wy = cy + (cos_alpha*d)

                            texX = int(wx*texture_scale)%texture.shape[0]
                            texY = int(wy*texture_scale)%texture.shape[1]

                            texture_clr = texture[texX, texY]
                            screenArray[x, y] = (texture_clr[0], texture_clr[1], texture_clr[2])
                        else:
                            if y < texture.shape[1]:
                                texY = int(y)%texture.shape[1]
                                texture_col = texture[texX, texY]
                                texture_col = [
                                    max(texture_col[0], 1),
                                    max(texture_col[1], 1),
                                    max(texture_col[2], 1)
                                ]
                                screenArray[x, y] = texture_col

@staticmethod
@njit
def rasterizeTextured(screenArray, x0, x1, y0, y1, y2, y3, c, fill_Portal, portal_buffer, ceiling_lut, floor_lut, texture, wy0, wy1, t0, t1, wall_length, wall_height, is_sky, yaw, v_offset, lighting):
    def lerp(a, b, c):
        return (1 - a) * b + a * c

    dx = max(x1 - x0, 1)
    sf = wall_length * 1  # Texture scaling factor
    texLeft = lerp(t0, 0, sf)
    texRight = lerp(t1, 0, sf)

    X0 = max(min(int(x0), W1), 1)
    X1 = max(min(int(x1), W1), 1)

    z0 = 1 / wy0
    z1 = 1 / wy1

    for x in prange(int(X0), int(X1)):
        # Interpolated Y coordinates
        t = (x - x0) / dx
        Y1 = int(lerp(t, y0, y1))
        Y2 = int(lerp(t, y2, y3))
        
        if is_sky:
            angle = np.atan((x - W2) / W2 * 0.70020718322)
            adjusted_angle = yaw + np.degrees(angle)
            texX = int(adjusted_angle / 360 * texture.shape[0]) % texture.shape[0]
        else:
            texX = int(lerp(1-t, texLeft / z0, texRight / z1) / lerp(1-t, wy0, wy1) * texture.shape[0]) % texture.shape[0]

        # Update ceiling and floor look-up tables
        if Y2 - Y1 == 0:
            ceiling_lut[x] = Y1
            floor_lut[x] = Y2

        for y in prange(int(Y2), int(Y1)):
            if 1 <= x <= W1 and 1 <= y <= H1:
                ceiling_lut[x] = Y1
                floor_lut[x] = Y2

                colAvg = sum(screenArray[x, y]) / 3
                isFilled = colAvg > 0

                if fill_Portal:
                    portal_buffer[x, y] = True
                elif not isFilled:
                    if is_sky:
                        if y < texture.shape[1]:
                            texY = y % texture.shape[1]
                            texture_col = texture[texX, texY]
                            screenArray[x, y] = texture_col
                    else:
                        # Wall texture rendering
                        a = (y - Y2) / (Y1 - Y2)
                        v = lerp(a*wall_height*0.1, 0, 1)
                        texY = int(v * texture.shape[1] + v_offset) % texture.shape[1]
                        texture_col = texture[texX, texY]
                        screenArray[x, y] = (
                            texture_col[0],
                            texture_col[1],
                            texture_col[2],
                        )
    return ceiling_lut, floor_lut


@staticmethod
@njit
def rasterizePortal(screenArray, portalArray, x0, x1, y0, y1, y2, y3, c, lighting):
    dx = max(x1-x0, 1)

    X0 = max(min(int(x0), W1), 1)
    X1 = max(min(int(x1), W1), 1)
    def lerp(a, b, c):
        return (1 - a) * b + a * c

    full = False
    if abs(X1-X0) == 0:
        X0 = 1
        X1 = W1
        full = True

    for x in prange(int(X0), int(X1)):
        if not full:
            t = (x - x0) / dx
            Y1 = int(lerp(t, y0, y1))
            Y2 = int(lerp(t, y2, y3))
        else:
            Y2 = 1
            Y1 = H1

        for y in prange(int(Y2), int(Y1)):
            if not (x > W1 or x < 1 or y > H1 or y < 1):
                isFilled = screenArray[x, y][0] > 0 or screenArray[x, y][1] > 0 or screenArray[x, y][2] > 0
                if not isFilled:
                    return False
    return True

@staticmethod
@njit
def rasterizeSprite(screenArray, entity_x, entity_y, sprite, entity_depth, entity_scale, f):
    
    sprite_width = sprite.shape[0]
    sprite_height = sprite.shape[1]

    sprite_width_offset = sprite_width/2
    sprite_height_offset = sprite_height/2
    
    xStart = int(entity_x)
    xEnd = int(entity_x+(sprite_width/entity_depth*entity_scale))

    yStart = int(entity_y)
    yEnd = int(entity_y+(sprite_height/entity_depth*entity_scale))

    for x in prange(xStart, xEnd):
        for y in prange(yStart, yEnd):
            X = int(x - sprite_width_offset/entity_depth*entity_scale)
            Y = int(y - sprite_height_offset/entity_depth*entity_scale)
            if X > 1 and X < W1 and Y > 1 and Y < H1:
                pixel_col = (255, 0, 0)
                colAvg = (screenArray[X, Y][0]+screenArray[X, Y][1]+screenArray[X, Y][2])/3
                isFilled = colAvg > 0
                if not isFilled:
                    texX = int((x-xStart)*entity_depth/entity_scale)
                    texY = int((y-yStart)*entity_depth/entity_scale)

                    pixel_col = sprite[texX, texY]
                    screenArray[X, Y] = pixel_col

@staticmethod
@njit(parallel=True, fastmath=True, cache=True)
def resetScreenArray(screenArray):
    for x in prange(screenArray.shape[0]):
        for y in prange(screenArray.shape[1]):
            screenArray[x, y] = (0,0,0)
    return screenArray

@staticmethod
@njit
def get_segment_normal(x0, y0, x1, y1):
    dx = x1-x0
    dy = y1-y0

    dist = 1+np.hypot(dx, dy)
    return dy/dist, -dx/dist


It's not immediately clear to me, as someone not so familiar with how your level is set up, what aspects of the screenshots are "as desired" versus which aspects show problems that need to be corrected. It might help to add a diagram, say from a top-down view, showing the camera position and a sequence of arrows from the camera to each node / portal it visits in turn (using numbers or colours to distinguish steps of iteration). That way you can clearly identify where you get an unwanted return to a previously-visited room, or abort such a return where it was actually desired.
